# Cannot find the "register" button anymore

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I was developing an Android application and I faced a small problem

Here is the sign up XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_signup"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email" />

    <requestFocus />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextFirstName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="First Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextLastName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Last Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextConfirmPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Confirm Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextAge"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Age" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mynumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Number +961"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:color="@color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Number" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_signup"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonCreateAccount"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                android:background="@color/androidwhite"
                android:text="Create Account" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And that's the `onCreate()` method of the sign up activity

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.signup);

// Get instance of the database adapter
loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

// Get references of views
mynumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mynumber);
editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
editTextFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFirstName);
editTextLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLastName);
editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
editTextConfirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);
editTextNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
mynumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mynumber);
editTextAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAge);

btnCreateAccount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);
btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

I don't know what went wrong, but I can't see the "create account" button anymore. Might be due to a change in the XML.

Comment: Your `Button` could have moved out of the screen. Use a `ScrollView`

Comment: delete android:layout_marginBottom="60dp" try again

Comment: @ZaferCelaloglu I tried didnt work :/

Comment: @Apoorv can you elaborate more on the ScrollView ?

Comment: @RoyMourad [ScrollView Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/scrollview/android-scrollview-example/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are setting your `EditText` width to `fill_parent` which takes the width of device and stops the buttons to dispay.

**Changes:** Changed the width and height of EditText to wrap_content

Try the following data :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#123456"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email" />

    <requestFocus />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextFirstName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="First Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextLastName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Last Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextConfirmPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Confirm Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextAge"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Age" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mynumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Number +961"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:color="@android:color/white" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Number" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonCreateAccount"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Create Account" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace :

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mynumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Number +961"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:color="@color/black" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Number" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_signup"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCreateAccount"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:background="@color/androidwhite"
            android:text="Create Account" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

by this, if you want your button to the right of editTextNumber :

```
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/mynumber" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Number +961" 
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:color="@color/black" /> 
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/EditTextNumber" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="Number" /> 
    <Button 
            android:id="@+id/buttonCreateAccount" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@color/white" 
            android:text="Create Account" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

or by this if your want your button under your editText :

```
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/mynumber" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Number +961" 
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:color="@color/black" /> 
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/EditTextNumber" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="Number" /> 
</LinearLayout>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/buttonCreateAccount" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:background="@color/white" 
    android:text="Create Account" />
```